# UWP Callback when connect/disconnect to a bluetooth devices

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth

We have a requirement to listen the Bluetooth connection changes:
such as: connect to a any BT devices, disconnect to a any BT devices.

Please note, it is not for monitoring certain BT devices status, it's for monitoring any BT devices connect/disconnect on Windows.

Is there any API (available for UWP) to support this feature? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Event [DeviceWatcher.Added](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.added?view=winrt-22621) and [DeviceWatcher.Removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher.removed?view=winrt-22621#windows-devices-enumeration-devicewatcher-removed) to monitor any Bluetooth devices connect/disconnect on Windows.

It is recommended that you refer to the [sample #DeviceEnumerationAndPairing](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs/Scenario2_DeviceWatcher.xaml.cs#L82) and choose to monitor Bluetooth devices. After the bluetooth device is disconnected or connected, you will receive the message.